# Adicionar migration e fazer update em tempo de execução EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e surgiu a necessidade de adicionar migration e executar o update em tempo de execução.

Já tenho toda a parte que carrega os módulos:

```
public class ClientContext : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        LoadModulos();
        LoadMaps(modelBuilder);
    }

    public static void LoadMaps(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        IEnumerable<Type[]> assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
            .GetAssemblies()
            .Where(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("NCode.")
                && a.FullName.Contains(".EF")
                && !a.FullName.Contains("NCode.EF")
                && a.GetTypes().Any(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith(".Map")))
            .Select(a => a.GetTypes().Where(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith(".Map")).ToArray());

        foreach (var types in assemblies)
        {
            foreach (var t in types)
            {

                // Verifica se classe pai do tipo (t) é a EntityTypeConfiguration<>
                var entityTypeConfiguration = typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>);
                var baseType = t.BaseType;
                if (!baseType.IsGenericType 
                    && baseType.IsGenericTypeDefinition
                    && !(baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == entityTypeConfiguration)) 
                {
                    continue;
                }


                // Tipo da entidade
                Type entityType = baseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                // Método Add da Configuration
                MethodInfo method = typeof(ConfigurationRegistrar).GetMethods()
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Add" && x.GetGenericArguments()[0].ToString().Equals("TEntityType"));

                // Trasforma em um generic method passando o Tipo da Entidade
                MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { entityType });

                // Cria a instancia do Map
                object map = (object)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

                try
                {
                    // Invoca o generic method passando a configurations a instancia do map 
                    genericMethod.Invoke(modelBuilder.Configurations, new object[] { map });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void LoadModulos()
    {
        NCodeSection configSection = (NCodeSection)
           System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("NCode");

        foreach (NCodeModuloElement customAssembly in configSection.Modulos)
        {
            try { Assembly.Load("NCode." + customAssembly.Nome + ".Model"); }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
            try { Assembly.Load("NCode." + customAssembly.Nome + ".EF"); }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
    }

    public ClientContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {

    }
```

Alguém tem alguma idéia de como fazer?

Comment: Procurando algo parecido para atualizações nos clientes encontrei este artigo que exemplifica o uso do migrations em runtime: https://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa ideia não faz muito sentido. Dentro da abordagem *Code First*, só faria sentido se você estivesse criando classes (*Models*) em tempo de execução também, assim como contextos e toda a estrutura envolvida.

Em resumo, **não tem como fazer**. *Migrations* podem ser executadas usando um comando PowerShell (`Update-Database`) ou utilizando um mecanismo de publicação (*Web Deploy*). É feito assim por questões estruturais: uma *Migration* **sempre** deve acompanhar uma mudança estrutural no seu conjunto de classes.

Ainda assim, se é mesmo necessário investir numa ideia assim, penso que os Frameworks estão sendo usados de uma forma **tremendamente** errada. Sugiro repensar esta parte da sua aplicação.

---

**EDIT**

Foi explicado por comentário que a ideia é construir uma aplicação por módulos. O problema é a abordagem. Com isso, toma-se como pressuposto que o ASP.NET MVC é modular, quando não é.

A maneira natural de fazer isso funcionar seria através de *Partial Classes*. O contexto teria que ser parcial e todas as classes de Model também. Agora, como ficariam as alterações que precisam ser feitas em *Controllers*? E em *Views* dependentes? Há, ainda, um agravante: as *Migrations* precisam ter uma ordem pré-definida. Como isto seria feito para módulos?

A resposta é: não seria. Não é possível. Se a ideia é trabalhar por "módulos", [é melhor usar a abordagem por áreas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28VS.100%29.aspx). Ela não influi no banco de dados: apenas em *Controllers* e *Views*. O contexto continua proveniente da raiz da aplicação.

---

**EDIT 2**

O autor da pergunta colocou um código que poderia ser factível com uma chamada dinâmica de *Migrations*. O problema é que aí não seria mais o padrão *Code First*: seria um novo padrão definido pelo autor da pergunta, em que todo o código de *Migrations* é gerado dentro da DLL.

Consequentemente, há uma série de erros que poderiam ocorrer, já que muito do que existe não funcionaria, e várias verificações manuais teriam de ser feitas pra executar o roteiro de configuração adequadamente.

Suponha agora que a aplicação ganhou dois módulos, e depois mais três. Se eu quisesse apenas ter o quarto módulo, não seria possível. Eu teria que ter todos os 4 primeiros módulos porque o esquema de *Migrations* é incremental.

Em outras palavras, seria uma reinvenção da roda.

Comment: Mas eu adicionarei classes em tempo de execução!

Comment: @RonaldoAsevedo Por que? Qual o objetivo?

Comment: Tipo assim estamos desenvolvendo sistema com módulos, e queria fazer que quando colocasse a dll do modulo por injeção de dependencia ele reconhece q tem entidades nova gera o migration e e faz o update para atualizar a base.

Comment: Sim, e como eu te falei, está errado. Não é assim que faz. Eu vou melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Ok, se não é assim, teria como me dar uma dica de como proceder?

Comment: @RonaldoAsevedo Veja se a resposta agora esclarece mais.

Comment: Esclareceu bem isso, mas eu já consegui fazer funcionar! as dependências e os mapeamentos, só precisava que ele gerasse automaticamente, como se o módulo fosse instalável!

Obs.: Ainda não estou trabalhando com as views, apenas arquitetura.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24697/discussion-between-ronaldo-asevedo-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).